# Mapping Permission with parent permissions in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, many-to-many

I created class `Permission` that is used to grant access to my application's components, then I wanted to map all needed permissions with Hibernate, but I faced problem:`AnnotationException: Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship: org.structure.business.Permission.permissions2`.

Permissions work like this: There is a root permission "READ", if you have root permission, then you can grant "EDIT", "CREATE", and "DELETE", you cannot delete if you can't read. So in list `parentPermissions` I simply store lower level permissions.

Permission entity:

```
@Entity(name = "PERMISSION")
public class Permission implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Permission> parentPermissions;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parentPermissions", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Permission> permissions2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

How can I map my Permissions?